# iOS AdMob : Error No Ad to Show

Tags: ios, objective-c, banner, admob

Currently using AbMob SDK version 7.29.0.

We are facing issue where we are unable to show ad and it giving us an error as follow:

```
adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: No ad to show.
```

It is working fine with iOS 11 and showing ad but it is causing issue with iOS 10.

Comment: Make sure Limit Ad Tracking (Settings/Privacy/Advertising) is off.

Comment: @ivarun yes i checked that its off. Even i checked with test ad unit ID which provided in demo its working.  But not working with my app ad unit ID. And yes i have create new ad unit ID by creating new app that also not work.

Comment: When you create new ad ID typically it will take 1-2 hours to active. Wait for few hours and try. let me know it is working for you or not.

Comment: @ivarun still received same error

Comment: same issue for me

Comment: @user3236289 You can add this below lines and check its working or not and if its work than when your app get live at that time you will able to get the ads.
let request =  GADRequest()
request.testDevices = ["2c4bfb4fb853b3d9b03c68578176d3a7"]
self.load(request)

Comment: Also make sure to add payment information to google Admob otherwise ads will not show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this and it will show ad in your device as well.

```
let request =  GADRequest()
request.testDevices = ["2c4bfb4fb853b3d9b03c68578176d3a7"]
self.load(request)
```

Also, it might be because you have not linked `Admob` ads to live application. Once your application is live and you connect it to `Admob`, it will start showing ad.

Remember, you won't be able to search your app while trying to connect to `Admob` immediately once the app is approved by `Apple`. This is because `Apple` will require sometime to index your app and Google also requires 1-2 days to refresh the cache to show your app in `Admob` searching result. So, wait for 2 days and try again to connect your app. Once you do this successfully, you will be able to see ads on your device as well.

Hope this helps.